# Shiny import data.table and manipulate it

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I am struggling on manipulating a data table that is imported on a shiny app. Particularly I would like to re-order the columns and delete some. I am trying to do this with the `data.table` package structure. For the re-ordering I am using `sortable::rank_list()` and `data.table::setcolorder()` and I have accomplished it but with the following `*Error in setcolorder: dt passed to setcolorder has no names*` appearing before the file is imported.

For deleting columns I would like to pass the name of the column to a `textInput` and only delete when pushing an `actionButton`. I am trying something like:

```
observeEvent(input$delete_col, {
 myData()[,input$delete_col_txt := NULL]
})
```

but no such luck.

Bellow my code and thanks for your time!

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Uploading Files in R"),

  fluidRow(
    column(4,
        wellPanel(
          navlistPanel(

            tabPanel("1. Import",

                     fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                              ".csv")),
                      tags$hr(),
                      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                  choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                              Semicolon = ";",
                                              Tab = "\t"),
                                  selected = ","),
                      textInput("nrows", "Rows", value = "Inf"
                                  )
                     ),

            tabPanel("2. Manipulations",
                    column(4, uiOutput("delete_column_txt"),
                              uiOutput("delete_column_btn"),),
                    column(8,uiOutput("rank_list_1"))

                     )
          )
        )

    ),
    mainPanel(
          DT::dataTableOutput('contents')
    )
  )

)


server <- function(input, output) {

  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=80*1024^3) # Maximum upload size allowed, in bytes

  myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data <- fread(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, nrows = as.numeric(input$nrows))
    return(data)
  })


  observeEvent(input$file1$datapath,{

    output$delete_column_txt <- renderUI({
      textInput("delete_col_txt", "Name of column to delete")
    })
    output$delete_column_btn <- renderUI({
      actionButton("delete_col", "Delete")
    })
    output$rank_list_1 <- renderUI({
          rank_list(
            text = "Set the order of columns",
            labels = as.list(names(myData())),
            input_id = "rank_list_1"
          )
        })

   })

  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({
      setcolorder(myData(), input$rank_list_1)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try putting `req(input$rank_list_1)` at the start of your `renderDataTable`.  if the renderer is called before `input$rank_list_1` has been given a value, you have problems.  You hint at the solution when you say "...before the file is imported".